# Saving a Date Time Value from different regions ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have developed a web application and it's running in 2 different countries. So in the controller, when a work record is created, I wrote like

```
model.Created_Date = DateTime.Now;
```

I hosted this application on Azure VM.

So when the record is saved, it's getting the server's current DateTime.

It's okay for 1 country but not for the other country. The country's time difference is 4 hours.

So when the log is created with the login time, Country 1 time should be 9.00 AM as well as the Country 2 person log in to the system where their time on 9.00 AM but the server took it as 1.00 PM.

How to fix this?

Comment: _"How to fix this?"_ - by using **only** UTC datetimes inside your application.

Comment: @Dai  like ``Model.CreatedDate = DateTime.UTC.Now;`` ?? I'm not sure how this get the exact country id because controller it self holds on the Azure VM and he get the server datetime right ?

Comment: When you use UTC you don't need to worry about countries and timezones.

Comment: @Dai So if I changed this to ``UTC.now`` the 4-hour time change how this will get from the controller ? how the controller knows this user from country 1 and he's time is this and another user from country 2 and his time is this ?

Comment: To get a user's current UTC offset, what I do is use a short JavaScript in the login form to capture their `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone` value and include it in an `<input type="hidden">` which then gets saved into their session (or just directly into their normal cookies) so it's available for every subsequent request.

Answer (score 1):

As you have been told, the only sane option is to **always** work with UTC timestamps inside your application.  The **only** place where you handle local times is at the *user interface* in places where timestamps are shown to, or input by, the user.

In other words:  You API must **always** send and receive UTC times.  Your API must never be bothered with local times.  It is up to the UI whether to show the UTC time or convert it to the user's local time.